# C# MySQL misinterpretation of field type

Tags: c#, mysql

I am facing an issue where C# appears to be misinterpreting a result data from a MySQL Stored Procedure.

The Stored Procedure returns 3 Int32 columns followed by 4 Varchar/String columns... or at least, it should.

Columns 1-5 return fine and so does column 7, however, for some reason, column 6 seems to be getting interpreted as an Image/Byte[] column and I have no idea why as the Stored Procedure definitely returns Varchar (255) column for this field.

I have never come across this problem before and extensive googling returns only unrelated problems. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the C# code;

```
using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "viewu";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("uname", "ausername");

    reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    dt1.Load(reader);

    gridControl1.DataSource = dt1;
}
```

I do not have access to the SP so I cannot post that code. However, below is an example result set. I suspect it's the value highlighted causing the issue, but no idea.

```
|ID1|ID2|Flagged|Att|Operation|Value|Type|
|---|---|-------|---|---------|-----|----|
|740|100|1      |   |=~       |NULL |User|
|740|100|1      |   |!*       |.    |Item|
|740|100|1      |   |:=       |PPP  |Item|
|740|100|1      |   |:=       |**base-qos-tp,bb-qos-sch-map,8m,bb-qos-cl-dscp,bb-qos-rw-1p,-24,-24**|Item|
|740|100|1      |   |:=       |8MOS |Item|
```

**UPDATE from comments**

- The provider is Connector/NET 6.9.7
- `dt1` is an untyped DataTable.
- The code of the stored procedure isn't available. The type of the sixth column (`Value`) was verified by the DBA to be `varchar(255)`.
- Specifying charset=utf8 and treat blobs as utfs=yes in the connection string has also unfortunately failed to resolve the issue.
- It is believed database version is 5.1.41

Comment: Code? Error messages?

Comment: Yeah. and "It should" - what about you make sure it does? And then post enough code to repro it. Help? Hire someone more competent. Want more - provide more info.

Comment: While there may be a problem with the driver you are using (which one? Connector/Net? something else?), the most likely reason is a problem either in the code or the stored procedure. Post the code and the messages. As it is, it's impossible to help, you don't even mention *what* is returned: a DataTable? A DataReader? An NHibernate entity?

Comment: No error messages encountered - Value column displays 'No image data' for all rows in that field, despite that clearly not being what gets returned from the SP. What code I have access to is above. Using latest version of MySQL dll I believe (6.9.7)

Comment: @TomTom - First time working with MySQL... So, yes, you're correct, the company should hire a MySQL person if they want a higher level of competency. But they haven't, so I have to go with what little knowledge (and access) I have. I have no documentation for the SP either

Comment: @KB54 this isn't about MySQL expertise but ADO.NET. You *still* haven't provided the schema for your DataTable. For all we know, you are using a typed table whose 6th DataColumn is `byte[]`. Why don't you *change* the column's type? If it is just a DataTable, why don't you define the columns in advance? Why are you sure this column is a `VARCHAR(255)`? Could it be a [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) type that your driver reads as a `byte[]` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you're misunderstanding the question... The point is that there isn't a schema for the DataTable, it's untyped... Hence it is being left to the compiler to decide what type it is. 

I have tried using a typed data set - changing the type of the column in the DataTable to anything other than a byte array results in "Inconvertible type mismatch between SourceColumn" 'Value' of Byte[] and the DataColumn 'Value' of String." error.

I am sure the column is Varchar(255) because the DBAs tell me that is what it is.

Comment: @KB54 I don't misunderstand the question. I'm saying that the question is vague and incomplete, which is why it has 2 close votes and 4 upvotes in the first comment for clarifications. You need to post the information in the *question itself*, not the comments. And you *still* haven't mentioned how you connect to MySQL. Are you using Connector/NET or not? And what version? Mappings are performed by the *driver*, not .NET

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As mentioned several comments ago... Using latest version of MySQL dll I believe (6.9.7)

Comment: @KB54 Please. Update the *question*, don't post comments. Other users will *not* try to read the comments. Comments can also get deleted at *any* time.

Comment: What is the codepage of the column and the database version? MySQL didn't support 4-byte UTF8 text before v 5.5.3, requiring the use of the ['Treat Blobs As UTF8'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-using-character-sets.html) setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found the reason for the misinterpretation i.e. root cause. However, I have found a suitable workaround.

In short, that workaround is to first type out the columns of the DataTable. Then to read the result row by row instead of just loading the result directly into the DataTable. Then to declare a byte array (b) in the below code and set it to null, later setting it to the result of the relevant column (value) in the below code. Then to use the default encoding (in my case) to convert to a string before finally adding a row to the datatable.

Full code below.

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

dt1.Columns.Add("ID1", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("ID2", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("Flagged", typeof(Boolean));
dt1.Columns.Add("Att", typeof(String));
dt1.Columns.Add("Operation", typeof(String));
dt1.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(String));
dt1.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(String));

MySqlDataReader reader = null;

using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
    connection.Open();

    try
    {

        using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.CommandText = "viewu";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("uname", "ausername");

            reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    byte[] b = null;

                    int ID1 = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    int ID2 = reader.GetInt32(1);
                    bool Flagged = reader.GetBoolean(2);
                    string Att = reader.GetString(3);
                    string Operation = reader.GetString(4);
                    b = (byte[])reader.GetValue(5);
                    string Type = reader.GetString(6);

                    string Value = Encoding.Default.GetString(b);

                    dt1.Rows.Add(1ID, ID2, Flagged, Attribute, Op, Value, Type);
                }
            }

            gridControl1.DataSource = dt1;
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps some who got a bit lost as I did